Family in a house trailer chased by a sect involving whole town
Family in a house trailer chased by a sect involving whole town 
At the beginning, a house trailer with a family are in the wild. Lights are off. the man of the family is watching at the distance something strange... A group of people (probably a sect) light a fire below a tree and then sacrificed a person. 
Then the wife from inside the trailer calls for his husband. And he says "don't turn on the lights". Then she says "why not?" and turned on the lights which makes the sect noticed the trailer. Then begins a chase in the whole town. It seemed that everybody in the town was participating in the chase. 
On the way, they found a school bus accident. The father says "there's no school on weekends" and sped up the trailer, crashing some cars to pass trough.  
And the end, having run many miles out of the highway, they stopped to rest.
Suddenly, near themm  a fire below a tree was started (same tree as the beginning) every person turns his head in slow motion as the movie ends in suspense.

I think the movie you are looking for is called "Race With the Devil."
A lot of the scenes you describe are listed here.  To list some of them, they are:
School bus part:

Alice and Kelly are in hysterics and exhausted from their ordeal. Frank continues driving but is forced to stop at the scene of an accident which is blocking the road. As they get closer to it, they realize a school bus is involved and Frank senses that it's a trick. Why? Because it's Sunday!

Tree on fire part:

Outside the motor home, a tree goes up in flames and loud chanting is audible. The couples look out the window and see a crowd of people in robes walking quickly towards them. Among them are the "nice" Henderson couple and Sheriff Taylor. Soon, the fire spreads around the RV and this time, there's no way out...

And the main characters appear to be in an RV.

Very fast! thank you!
"If you race with the devil, you better be faster than hell"
